How can I prevent custom macros in mathlife from losing their arguments?
I'm trying to use mathlife with "atomic" elements that are generated from the environment.   One way to get atomic elements is by defining a macro.  So, a defined a macro as
  prop: {
    args: 2,
    def: '\\,\\text{#1}^\\text{#2}\\,{}',
    captureSelection: true, // not editable
    expand: false       // keep as macro
  },

The macros are used in the initial system proposed equation and may be inserted from the customized menu.   All that works great.  I can also copy/paste these elements.  It goes wrong at the moment that I edit the equation using the keyboard.  Most works fine, but after I enter '*' (multiplication), I get a \cdot in the formula, but the LaTeX returned from getValue('latex') loses the arguments on \prop.  For example:
Before: \prop{x}{obj} = t (renders fine, returns this as LaTeX value)
Now, after typing '*', the display looks fine, but getValue('latex') returns
After: \prop=t\cdot, while the display still looks pretty.
I can ask for getValue('latex-expanded').  That works fine, but that means I need to convert the expanded text back to \prop{x}{obj} myself.
Is there anything that can be done against this?   All I want is to add elements as atomic in the initial equation, allow inserting through the menu and get it back as macro from getValue('latex').
